# How to set the background of jQueryUI Dialog for v1.8x

Tags: jquery-ui

I'd like to provide a .png that renders as the background of a jQueryUI-based dialog object. [This posting references the use of an 'overlay:' parameter](http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-ui-the-dialog-part2) but 'overlay' is not listed in the current documentation.

What's the current method to achieve this effect?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use CSS to accomplish this.  Just set a `background-image: url(...)` on the `div` you're making into a dialog ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image)'s more about `background-image`).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/S5pmw/

**Edit:** Just [looking at the 1.6 code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.6/jquery-ui.js), it looks like you could specify CSS rules for the `overlay` that appears behind the dialog (if you specify modal).  It doesn't control the actual background of the dialog itself, and it looks like this option was removed in 1.7(3).  [Here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-dialog-documentation-is-missing-overlay-option)'s a related jQuery forum thread about the option.  Excerpt:

> The overlay option was removed in
>   favor of defining styles in your
>   stylesheet. The overlay div has a
>   class of ui-widget-overlay.

So to accomplish the behavior the `overlay` option gave you, you just need to define CSS rules for `ui-widget-overlay`.

Comment: Thankx - that's a functional replacement for the code sample referenced above but since i'm trying to adopt (jqueryUI usage for sake of a more unified learning curve) it would be helpful to understand if overlay was removed from the UI's dialog since that tutorial was written or i was mis-interpreting the directions.

Comment: @justSteve: I'm pretty sure that `overlay` refers to the dimmed/semi-transparent layer that appears under a modal dialog.  I'll do some digging and find out for sure.

Comment: @justSteve: I did some more research and updated my answer.  Looks like the jQueryUI team removed that option after 1.6 and that the tutorial is out of date.